# I want a new line when i iterate the same json while using it in lambda ( Python ) but getting error

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want a new line when i iterate the same json while using it in lambda ( Python ) but getting error

Below is the code sample :

```
import json


eventToUpload ={"type":"new","version":"2.4.0"}

uploadByteStream = bytes(json.dumps(eventToUpload).encode('UTF-8')) 

m = uploadByteStream *3

print(m)
```

and This is the output

```
'{"type": "new", "version": "2.4.0"}{"type": "new", "version": "2.4.0"}{"type": "new", "version": "2.4.0"}'
```

But i want the json to have new like something like this

```
b'{"type": "new", "version": "2.4.0"}
{"type": "new", "version": "2.4.0"}
{"type": "new", "version": "2.4.0"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate it into a list, and use `join` to insert newlines between them before encoding.

```
js = json.dumps(eventToUpload)
uploadByteStream = '\n'.join([js for _ in range(3)]).encode('UTF-8')
```

You don't need to call `bytes()`, since `str.encode()` returns a byte string.

Comment: Its still not working. getting this - **b'{"type": "new", "version": "2.4.0"}\n{"type": "new", "version": "2.4.0"}\n{"type": "new", "version": "2.4.0"}'** I had tried this earlier

Comment: When you print a byte string, control characters are not interpreted, they're just printed as escape sequences. So there's no way to make it actually break the line in a byte string.

Comment: But the newline character is in there, you see it as `\n`